# What is the best way to restructure this sklearn class wrapper to avoid redundancy?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have trained multiple models in the form of Pipelines through sklearn, and I am creating a module of multiple classes that load these trained models.

For example, I trained a LogisticRegression Pipeline that I am loading in the following way:

```py
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
import joblib

class LogRegModel:
   def __init__(self, path):
      self.model = joblib.load(model_path)
   
   def predict(self, documents):
      return self.model.predict(documents)
   
   def predict_proba(self, documents):
      return self.model.predict_proba(documents)
```

Right away, it doesn't seem right that I am writing functions into my class that already exist in my Pipeline object that I am loading into the class. I feel like this is an inheritance issue but I'm not sure how I could restructure this class so that I don't have to rewrite these functions.

I am also planning on writing two more classes for different models, all sklearn pipelines who have the methods `predict` and `predict_proba`. It seems redundant to overwrite these methods when I am essentially doing the same thing after overwriting them.

Any help on how I can better structure my code to avoid redundancy would be much appreciated. The reason I'm doing this in the first place is to create a library where these pretrained models can be easily imported and accessed by other people.

Thanks.